# zend htaccess public php file

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess

is there any way to access e.g. prolink.php file in zend /public directory by typing mydomain.com/prolink.php, and go to application in other cases (index.php)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

should I specify a route for that?

Comment: Add `RewriteRule ^prolink.php$ /public/prolink.php` above the other lines.

Comment: RewriteRule is fine, but I accomplished it with RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^prolink.php$ public/prolink.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
If the request is for a file that exists already on the server, index.php isn't served.

Comment: Nice work. (You'll probably want to add that `-f` condition to the second rule too.)

Answer (score 0):

put index.php file into the public folder
and put .htaccess in the root folder, witch contents

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

Options -Indexes
```